# Object is possibly 'undefined' error even after checking that object and property exists

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm getting an `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` error on every property check and access after `story &&` on the code below. It doesn't make sense to me, since the first check is checking whether `story` exists, or not. If it didn't exist, wouldn't the ternary just short circuit, and return `null`? I'm new to typescript (and newish to react). I'd be happy to hear any suggestions! Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getStory } from "../services/hnAPI";

interface Props {
  storyId: number;
}

export const Story: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [story, setStory] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    getStory(props.storyId).then((data) => data && data.url && setStory(data));
  }, [props.storyId]);
  return story && story.url ? (
    <a href={story.url}>{story.title}</a>
  ) : null;
};
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Ideally someone could drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Right now I don't have access to `"../services/hnAPI";` so I get a bunch of errors.  Perhaps the issue is that `useState()` is inferring `undefined` instead of the type you want, and you'll have to specify it yourself like `const [story, setStory] = useState<StoryOrWhatever>();` but I don't know because I can't test it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be passing a type argument to `useState()` so it does not infer the state value as `undefined`.

Here is an example

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getStory } from '../services/hnAPI';

interface Props {
  storyId: number;
}

interface Story {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  url: string;
  // properties for the Story
}

export const Story: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [story, setStory] = useState<Story | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getStory(props.storyId).then((data: Story) => data && setStory(data));
  }, [props.storyId]);
  return story && story.url ? <a href={story.url}>{story.title}</a> : null;
};
```

P.S. Please never let a promise get uncatched. If you are making a API call is you `getStory` function consider adding a `catch` block and properly handle the error. Example in the same scenario.

```
export const Story: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [story, setStory] = useState<Story | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getStory(props.storyId).then((data: Story) => data && setStory(data))
      .catch(error => {
          // handle the error
          // you can use another state variable to store the error
      });
  }, [props.storyId]);
  return story && story.url ? <a href={story.url}>{story.title}</a> : null;
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks subash! I'll learn how to add the catch block now!

Comment: Great. Here are some resource for learning more about error handling with promises [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)